# Get JSON data from ajax call to PHP page through POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to get some data from a form making AJAX call. I am getting the data as a string in my PHP page. The string looks like

'fname':'abc','lname':'xyz','email':'','pass':'','phone':'','gender':'','dob':''

Now I want to convert this entire string into array which would look like
 ["fname"] => "abc",
 ["lname"] => "xyz"... and so on

The ajax call is like below:

```
fname = $("#form-fname").val();
lname = $("#form-lname").val();
email = $("#form-username").val();
pwd = $("#form-password").val();
phone = $("#form-phone").val();
gender = $("#form-gender").val();
dob = $("#form-dob").val();
var user = {"fname":fname,"lname":lname,"email":email,"pass":pwd,"phone":phone,"gender":gender,"dob":dob};
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "doRegistration.php",
      data: user
 })
 .done(function( msg ) {                        
       window.location.href = "../profile.php";
 })
 .fail(function(msg) {
       sessionStorage.setItem("success","0");
       window.location.reload();
 });
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("log1.txt",$content); //This produces the string I get above
```

Now I try to convert the string into array as above

```
$dec = explode(",",$content);
$dec1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($dec);$i++)
{
    $dec1[i] = substr($dec[i],strpos($dec[i],":"));
}
//After this $dec1 is empty and count($dec1) gives 0.
```

But this does not give me the required array. I have checked several answers here, but they do not solve my issue. I tried to google but did not find any resolution. Is there something wrong in the code? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split your $dec values by ':' then from that result the [0] element is your associated array key, and the [1] is your assoicated array value.  Then json_encode that associated array at the end.

Comment: @Taplar if I split it using ':', then I get something like ["fname"]->"abc,lname",["xyz,email"]->"email" and so on...

Comment: You don't split $content by ':'.  You split each $dec string by ":"  The entire string consists of name value pairs separated by comma, and each name value pair separated by colon.  Thus you have to unwind that, the comma being the outer most separator, and then the colon being the inner seperator for each of those tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change quotes and add braces. Then you can decode resulting json

```
$string = "'fname':'abc','lname':'xyz','email':'','pass':'','phone':'','gender':'','dob':''";

print_r(json_decode('{' . str_replace("'", '"', $string) . '}', true));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [fname] => abc
    [lname] => xyz
    [email] => 
    [pass] => 
    [phone] => 
    [gender] => 
    [dob] => 
)
```

Comment: I tried this also like $test = json_decode('{' . str_replace("'", '"', $string) . '}', true); and when I check the type of $test by  gettype($test), I get it as null

Comment: I had to do one tweak in your solution, $te = str_replace('"',"",$string); because the string itself carried "" with it. After removing them, your solution worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you are using the index of the for loop for the key of the array. If you are trying to archive (I believe it is called dictionary in Java). You can try the following code:

```
<?php
$string = "'fname':'abc','lname':'xyz','email':'','pass':'','phone':'','gender':'','dob':''";
$pieces=explode(',',$string);
foreach($pieces as $array_format){
list($key,$value) = explode(':',$array_format);
$array[$key]=$value;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I cannot see any value when I try to do file_put_content("file.txt",$array["fname"]); Is there something wrong? I hope "fname" should be the key

Comment: Hey there, the $string variable should be the one that you get from the file_get_content.
It is really close to your code mentioned above:
    $pieces = explode(",",$content);
    foreach($pieces as $array_format){
         list($key,$value) = explode(':',$array_format);
         $array[$key]=$value;
    }